# Launching PDF reader on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, storagefile

I'm trying to launch pdf reader with the code below but it does not work. Can somebody help me?

```
    private async Task<StorageFile> WriteData(string fileName, byte[] data)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (Stream s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            s.Close();
        }

        return file;
    }

    private async Task<bool> OpenPdf(StorageFile file) 
    {

        var uri = new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

        return result;
    }

    private async void FetchPdf() {
         // Fetch pdf bytes to network
         //....
         StorageFile file = await WriteData("test.pdf", data);

         if (file != null) {
            bool result = await OpenPdf(file);     
            if (result)
              Debug.WriteLine("Success");
            else 
              Debug.WriteLine("Cannot open pdf file.");
         }
    }
```

result is always false and so launcher is not presented.

I used LaunchUriAsync because LaunchFileAsync is not implemented on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LaunchUriAsync` isn't supported on Windows Phone 8 per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx). It throws an exception if called

You can use `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync` to launch a `StorageFile`.

This code works for example (assming there's a file called `"metro.pdf"` in the project, with the `Build Action` set to `Content`, with `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy if Newer`).

```
var installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var assets = await installedLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var pdf = await assets.GetFileAsync("metro.pdf");
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdf);
```

Comment: was misled by the documentation in visual studio as you can see here: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/881x175q90/401/pozq.png

Comment: Can i test this on Emulator  ?

Comment: @user2056563 I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @WiredPrairie ok just have a look at it here ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011326/open-pdf-file-in-emulator

Comment: Awesome dude... +1.
This work fine, just put the anyFile.pdf in Assets folder, and make its build action to Content, and then Just make the function Async ... and then Put "await" before Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdf);
 it worked fine for me. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Called the API and saved the byte array to file

```
    public static async void WriteDataToIsolatedStorageFile(string fileName, byte[] data)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                if ((data != null) && (data.Length > 0))
                {
                    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

opened the file in pdf reader using

```
    private async void StartExternalPDFApp()
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = await FileManager.FindDirectory(FileManager.RelativeStorageDirectoryLocalStorage);
        StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(PdfFileName);
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(storageFile);
    }
```

localFolder is Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder

Answer (score 0):

just put the anyFile.pdf in Assets folder, and make its build action to Content, and then Just make the function Async ... and then Put "await" before Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdf);
 it worked fine for me. Nice.
See this.

```
     private async void privacyPolicy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
        var installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        var assets = await installedLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
        var pdf = await assets.GetFileAsync("PrivacyPolicy.pdf");
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdf);
    }
```