# PDF not opening on WP8 device

Tags: c#, silverlight, pdf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have few pdf in a folder say Data/PDF/abc.pdf.

I am trying to open PDF with the below code:

```
private async void LaunchPDFNew(string name)
        {
            string imageFile = @"Data/PDF/"+name+".pdf";

            // Get the image file from the package's image directory
            var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);
            if (file != null)
            {
                bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
                if (success)
                {
                    // File launched
                    Debug.WriteLine("File Launched");
                }
                else
                {
                    // File launch failed
                    Debug.WriteLine("File Launched Failed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Could not find file
                Debug.WriteLine("Could not find the file");
            }
        }
```

It gives me Error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

I have tried with the solution given in below link as well

[Launching PDF reader on windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741339/launching-pdf-reader-on-windows-phone-8?lq=1)

But neither of them is working.How to fix this ?

Comment: there is one more overload to this method which do not uses the second argument(options), try that one.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal Can you please give me a pointer(link) on that ?

Comment: Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file); use this method

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal ok, i wil try that

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal I have checked it and its not working, is there any other way ?

Comment: at which line are you getting this exception? is file null? Put breakpoints and check.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal its crashing at this like var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile with the error which i have added in question

Answer (score 0):

For all those people where they are not able to open the PDF.

1) Assming there's a file called "abc.pdf" in the project, with the Build Action set to Content, with Copy to Output Directory set to Copy if Newer)

2) If the pdf file is in the directory then use `\` and not `/`, so

```
string file = @"Data/PDF/"+name+".pdf";
```

should be

```
string file = @"Data\PDF\"+name+".pdf";
```

3) And finally use this:

```
private async void LaunchPDF(string name)
        {
            string file = @"Data\PDF\"+name+".pdf";

            // Get the image file from the package's image directory
            var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);
            if (file != null)
            {
                bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
                if (success)
                {
                    // File launched
                    Debug.WriteLine("File Launched");
                }
                else
                {
                    // File launch failed
                    Debug.WriteLine("File Launched Failed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Could not find file
                Debug.WriteLine("Could not find the file");
            }
        }
```