# How to read a PDF file?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 app, and I need to open PDF files from local storage in the app. I have no clue how to do it.

Just able to extract the text from the PDF would also work.

Comment: is it to open from the local storage or from the project? IF it's from the project you could refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741339/
But I still don't know whether it would support for 8.1 too.

Comment: Do you mean read the pdf file into your app or launch another app to view the PDF?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I want to read the pdf in my app, or even just extracting the text out of the pdf would work.

Comment: Maybe http://mupdf.com/

Comment: Apitron pdf rasterizer and pdf kit both have support for windows phone. Text extraction and text search are accessible with just a few calls. It's a paid component.

Answer (score 0):

[`Windows.Data.Pdf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263465) API is only limited to Windows 8.1 You can check out 3rd party SDKs

[ComponentOne PDF Viewer](https://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use itextsharp library for silverlight/windows phone apps.